# How does the immune system distinguish between commensal and pathogenic bacteria?

Tags: immunology

There are billions of bacteria living harmlessly in our gut, and in fact most are helpful to us, aiding digestion, producing vitamins and maintaining gut health. The immune system is able to suppress immune responses against these organisms, avoiding killing such beneficial microorganisms in this way. However, it is still able to detect and mount an immune response against those microorganisms that are or would be pathogenic. How does it distinguish them?

Comment: [This](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjyquL-s-LSAhVJOI8KHc_kCMoQFgg9MAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.methodquarterly.com%2F2015%2F11%2Fself-vs-non-self%2F&usg=AFQjCNEkp-OUWDqBSXLoC5TmJH66CIoM0g) can be a good reading.